# HtmlAgilityPack неправильно парсит

Tags: c#, .net, htmlagilitypack

Пытался спарсить страницу на Selenium через XPath, выдает нужную информацию. А на HtmlAgilityPack выдает одно и тоже не верное значение. Уже бьюсь 2-ой день: экранировал кавычки, прямой путь давал, указывал class этого элемента в котором текст. Голова уже дымиться) Какой нужно задать XPath?

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
string url = (@"https://www.g2a.com/ak-47-redline-field-tested.html");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlNodeCollection nodes;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2906.0 Safari/537.36");
string html = webClient.DownloadString(url);
doc.LoadHtml(html);
nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//*[@id=\"g2a-offer-wrapper\"]//div[4]/div[1]//text()");
string outputText = " ";
foreach (HtmlNode HN in nodes)
{
    outputText = HN.InnerText;
}

listBox1.Items.Add(outputText);
```

Это 1 из примеров, всегда выводит `0,00 руб.`

Comment: По указанной ссылке лучше использовать такой запрос `//div[@class='selected-price']/text()`.
Насколько я понимаю продукт всегда на странице один. Зачем вы делаете `SelectNodes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема вовсе не в XPath. Дело в том, что цена подгружается через скрипты, но `DownloadString` не возвращает результат их выполнения. Именно поэтому вам возвращается `0,00 руб.`

---

Если воспользоваться Fiddler`ом, то мы увидим, что после нашего целевого запроса выполняется еще несколько. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один из них, помимо прочего и возвращает цену продукта:

```
"f":"356,46
```

Соответственно, вам нужно делать все эти запросы через код, чтобы спарсить цену.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, теперь понятно куда смотреть.

Comment: @AlexandrVolkov, Пожалуйста! Рад, что помог.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже у вас опечатка в цикле, поменяйте на:

```
foreach (HtmlNode HN in nodes) 
{
    outputText = HN.InnerText;
    listBox1.Items.Add(outputText);
}
```

Comment: Так не в этом проблема, а в Xpath

Comment: @AlexandrVolkov, как я понял xpath нашел что-то, так что он рабочий, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Да он находит, но совсем не то, что нужно. Хотя адрес указывает на единственный элемент, он парсит совсем другое.

Comment: @AlexandrVolkov, вам стоит в вопрос добавить какие данные нужно было получить (мне показалось, что у вас проблема в том, что всегда последнее совпадение `0,00 руб.` находит)